# Redux async action not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this async action in my app that's not working correctly. I reckon the error is in `mapDispatchToProps` .

Here is `mapDispatchToProps`:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      fetchUserList: () => {
        console.log('---In fetchUserList---');
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USER_LIST,
          payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log('xhr: ', xhr);
            xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/data/fetch/users');
            xhr.onload = () => {
              console.log(' --- in onload function ---');
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
            xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log(' --- in onerror function ---');
              reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
            xhr.send();
          })
        });
      }
```

I have logged `fetchUserList`  at several steps which do **show up on log** but the method neither reaches `xhr.onload` or `xhr.onerror` since I do not get any logs from there is it **correctly setup** ?

Here is the component I am using it in:

```js
class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUserList();
  }

}
```

Comment: Does it reach `xhr.send()`?

Comment: @ Joshua R Yep I got 200 ok on a request as well as the preview of the data

Comment: I think you should consider [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) for handling your async-actions. It is middleware written by the author of redux for that express purpose. At that link he has an amazing written walkthrough of how to use thunks, how to compose them, use them to dispatch actions within actions to handle error cases etc. Great source of knowledge, props to [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/gaearon). Pun intended!

Answer (score 0):

as suggested above, your actions should be pure java script objects, if you wish to make a